# How can I remove react-native-swiper-flatlist last swiper dots?

Tags: react-native

How can I remove react-native-swiper-flatlist last child swipe pagination dots? I tried some way, but it seems impossible. Please, help me.

```
<View style={styles.container}>
    <SwiperFlatList
      autoplay={false}
      autoplayLoop={false}
      index={0}
      showPagination
      showButtons
      paginationDefaultColor={'gainsboro'}
      paginationActiveColor={'orangered'}
    >
     <View style={styles.child}>
        <Image style={styles.img} source={pic} />
        <Text style={styles.text}>Biz sizə nə vəd edirik ?</Text>
        <Text style={styles.smallText}>Dizaynın qiymətləndirilməsində, oxunan mətnin oxucunun diqqətini yayındırması bir həqiqətdir. Lorem Ipsum istifadə etmənin əsas məqsədi odur.</Text>
     </View>
      <View style={styles.child}>
        <Image style={styles.img} source={pic} />
        <Text style={styles.text}>Sizin rahatlığınız üçün çalışırıq</Text>
        <Text style={styles.smallText}>Dizaynın qiymətlən   dirilməsində, oxunan mətnin oxucunun diq qətini yayındırması bir həqiqətdir. Lorem Ipsum istifadə etmənin əsas məqsədi odur.</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.child}>
        <Image style={styles.img} source={pic} />
        <Container>
            <Content>
               <Text style={styles.text}>Daima yanınızdayıq!</Text>
               <Text style={styles.smallText}>Dizaynın qiymətləndirilməsində, oxunan mətnin oxucunun diqqətini yayındırması bir həqiqətdir. Lorem Ipsum istifadə etmənin əsas məqsədi odur.</Text>
               <Button color='red' block style={styles.buttonStyle}>
                   <Text>Başla</Text>
               </Button>
            </Content>
         </Container>
      </View>
    </SwiperFlatList>
  </View>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the pagination property
"showPagination"

```
<SwiperFlatList
      autoplay={false}
      autoplayLoop={false}
      index={0}
      showButtons
      paginationDefaultColor={'gainsboro'}
      paginationActiveColor={'orangered'}
    >
```

working example: https://snack.expo.io/@msbot01/sliderpagination

Comment: I want only remove last slide pagination

Comment: and add button instead of dots

Comment: So add the property -------------
onMomentumScrollEnd={()=>{Alert.alert('end')}} -----------In this when the scroll ends do what ever steps you want to